# grep the folder using sed command in shell script

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I am trying to grep the folder name from full tar file. Below is the example.

example:

```
TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86_64.tar.gz
```

I want to grep the folder name (**TEST-5.3.0.0-build1**) in shell script

So i tried below command for grep

```
$ package_folder=$(echo TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86_64.tar.gz | sed -e "s/.[0-9]*[a-z]*[0-9]*.tar.gz$//" | sed -e 's/\/$//')
```

But I am getting below output:

```
$ echo $package_folder
```

TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86

Could you please anyone correct me where I am doing mistake. I need folder name as TEST-5.3.0.0-build1

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: better I can use uname -m instead of hardcode of architecture. But When I am trying it was throwing an error "s/.uname -m.tar.gz$//"  ... can you please advise

Answer (score 1):

In your command, you do not match `_`, `x`, etc. The `[0-9]*[a-z]*[0-9]*` only matches a sequence of zero or more digits, zero or more (lowercase) letters, and zero or more digits. It is better to use a `[^.]*` to match any chars other than `.` between two `.` chars. Also, literal dots must be escaped, or an unescaped `.` will match any single char.

You can use

```sh
sed 's/\.[^.]*\.tar\.gz$//'
```

Or, just use string manipulation *if* `x86_64` is also a constant:

```sh
s='TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86_64.tar.gz'
s="${s/.x86_64.tar.gz/}"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/S1lyQf):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86_64.tar.gz'

package_folder=$(sed 's/\.[^.]*\.tar\.gz$//' <<< "$s")
echo "${package_folder}"
# => TEST-5.3.0.0-build1

s="${s/.x86_64.tar.gz/}"
echo "$s"
# => TEST-5.3.0.0-build1
```

Comment: FYI, `s="${s/.$(uname -m).tar.gz/}"` also [works](https://ideone.com/VsNTnd).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uname -m` in replacement part of this string:

```sh
s='TEST-5.3.0.0-build1.x86_64.tar.gz'
echo "${s%.$(uname -m)*}"

TEST-5.3.0.0-build1
```

Or using `sed`:

```sh
sed "s/\.$(uname -m).*//" <<< "$s"

TEST-5.3.0.0-build1
```